# mocha nesting/replicating tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Given a data structure that satisfies some invariants, I would like to test the state of an instance of the data structure after various operations.  What is the best way to do this?

```
describe('data-structure', function() {
  var x;

  beforeEach(function() {
    x = getDataStructure();
  });

  describe('satisfies invariants', function() {
    // run tests on 'fresh' x

    it('should ...', function() { 
      // ...
    });

    // ...
  });

  describe('operation 1', function() {
    it('should preserve invariants', function() {
      x.doSomething();
      // run 'satisfies invariants' tests on modified x
    });
  });
});
```

I thought about using an `afterEach` hook, but I do not think `x` is preserved there?

```
afterEach(function() {
  // somehow run 'satisfies invariants' test
});
```

It maybe be that I can refactor `'satisfies invariants'` into a method, but it would be nice if mocha could report which invariant-tests failed for each operation, e.g.

```
data-structure
  satisfies invariants
    should satisfy invariant 1 ...
    ...

  operation 1
    should satisfy invariant 1 ...
    ...

  operation 2
    should satisfy invariant 1 ...
    ...
```

---

## Edit

Using the structure

```
describe('data-structure', function() {
  var x;

  describe('satisfies invariants', function() {
    afterEach(function() {
      it('should satisfy invariant 1', function() { 
        // x.value === a again
        // ...
      });

      // ...
    });

    it('should work after operation 1', function() {
      x = getDataStructure(); // x.value === a
      x.operation1(); // x.value === b
    });

    it('should work after operation 2', function() {
      x = getDataStructure();
      x.operation2();
    });

    // ...
  });
});
```

does not seem to preserve the changes to `x`.

Comment: Yeah, within the afterEach you'll have the freshly created object put in `x` as modified by the single test executed. If you want to test it after all tests have executed, use `before` and `after` in place of their `*Each` counterparts.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct.  Do I need to pass the modified `x` to the `afterEach` method somehow?

Comment: No, the function you submit to `afterEach` has a scope chain that still contains that variable. Keep in mind that, after a test, `afterEach` will be executed before the `beforeEach` for the next test.

Comment: Does a `beforeEach` in a scope enclosing an `afterEach` run before each test contained within that `afterEach`?

Comment: I will edit the post so you can see what I am currently doing.

Comment: Wait, the `beforeEach`, the `afterEach`, and all the `it` statements I'm speaking of are at the same level within the `describe` block, as from the example.

Comment: OK, you want to execute a check at the end of the block called "satisfies invariants", don't you?

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the current structure.  In the `satisfies invariants` block, I want every test within `afterEach` to run after each test in `satisfies invariants`, e.g. `should work after operation 1`.  However!  each "operation" test modifies `x` and I want each test within the `afterEach` to run on that modified `x`.  Note that each "operation" test modifies `x` in a different way.

Comment: OK, understood. I'm at work now, let me come back to home and I'll add an answer that should solve your problems. Think in the meantime of using `assert` as a library to check invariants, instead of a set of functions as above. Oh, yes, your example doesn't work, I haven't been able to explain what I mean with no code, but I'm short in time when at work (usually I reply while having a smoke). I'm sorry. An example will follow.

Comment: Haha, I appreciate the help!  Take your time.

Answer (score 0):

It follows an example, let me know if I forget something of what we have discussed:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('data-structure', function() {
    var x;

    beforeEach(function() {
        // freshly created data structure for each describe block below
        x = getDataStructure;
    });

    describe('satisfies invariants', function() {
            after(function() {
                // it executes those tests only once after all the it block below
                assert(x); // put your tests here
            });

            it('op 1.1', function() {
                do_something_on(x);
            });

            it('op 1.2', function() {
                // keep in mind that x is the same instance of the previous test
                do_something_else_on(x);
            });

            // so on
    });

    describe('satisfies something else', function() {
            // here you have a new instance of x, because of the outer beforeeach

            after(function() {
                // it executes those tests only once after all the it block within this describe block
                assert(x); // put your tests here
            });

            it('op 2.1', function() {
                do_something_on(x);
            });

            it('op 2.2', function() {
                // keep in mind that x is the same instance of the previous test, but not the one used in 1.2
                do_something_else_on(x);
            });

            // so on
    });

    // so on
});
```

This piece of code should give you an idea of which instance is accessible and where.
If it lacks something, let me know and I'll have a go to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

Mocha does not support putting `it` inside a hook like you do in your last snippet. (`afterEach` is a hook). In some trivial cases you may get the desired behavior but that's just luck. Once you move on to more complicated test suites, you won't get the behavior your expect.

Moreover, I suggest that `afterEach` is the wrong place for that kind of test. You should use the hooks only to setup and tear down your test environment and not for performing assertions on the state of your code. Mocha treats any failure in a hook as "the test suite is broken, abort!!" rather than as a test failure. Look at this example, for instance:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe("test", function () {
    var x;

    beforeEach(function () {
        x = { foo: 'something' };
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        assert(x.foo === 'something');
    });

    it("one", function () {});

    it("two", function () {
        x.foo = 'something else';
    });

    it("three", function () {});
});
```

In theory there's no reason test `three` should not run but when the failure occurs in the `afterEach` hook after test `two` is run, Mocha will just stop running tests there. The output (omitting the final stack trace) is:

```
  test
    ✓ one 
    ✓ two 
    1) "after each" hook


  2 passing (14ms)
  1 failing
```

Note how `two` is marked as passing but the hook failed. And note how `three` is never even attempted. As soon as there is a failure in a hook, Mocha stops right there.

#### The Solution

You should just create a function that you call from each test to test your invariants. For instance:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe("test", function () {
    var x;

    beforeEach(function () {
        x = { foo: 'something' };
    });

    function testInvariant() {
        assert(x.foo === 'something');
    }

    it("one", function () {
        testInvariant();
    });

    it("two", function () {
        x.foo = 'something else';
        testInvariant();
    });

    it("three", function () {
        testInvariant();
    });
});
```

If you run Mocha on the code above, you'll get (again, omitting the final stack trace):

```
  test
    ✓ one 
    1) two
    ✓ three 


  2 passing (10ms)
  1 failing
```

`two` was marked as failed and Mocha moved on to run `three`, which was successful.

If you don't want to write `testInvariant()` in each test you could create a function that adds it for you. For instance:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe("test", function () {
    var x;

    beforeEach(function () {
        x = { foo: 'something' };
    });

    function makeTest(name, fn) {
        it(name, function () {
            fn();
            assert(x.foo === 'something');
        });
    }

    makeTest("one", function () {
    });

    makeTest("two", function () {
        x.foo = 'something else';
    });

    makeTest("three", function () {
    });
});
```

This produces the same output as the previous code snippet.